# Proving $m_4m_2\geq m_3^2+m_2^2$

Tags: statistics, inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, means, moment-problem

I've been trying to prove: $m_4m_2\geq m_3^2+m_2^2$

How I proceeded:

From the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality:

$m_3=E[(x-\bar{x})^3]$

$m_2=E[(x-\bar{x})^2]$

$m_4=E[(x-\bar{x})^4]$

$[E(XY)]^2 \leq E[X^2] \cdot E[Y^2]$

So, $m_3^2=[E(x-\bar{x})(x-\bar{x})^2]^2 \leq E[(x-\bar{x})^2] \cdot E(x-\bar{x})^4]$

But this gives $m_3^2 \leq m_4m_2$

Here, $m_r$ are central moments

This isn't what I wanted. Am I in the wrong here?

Comment: something seems wrong about the inquality...

Comment: Something is wrong because it is not homogeneous. Replace $x$ by $y = \overline{x} + \lambda (x - \overline{x})$.

Comment: It must be $m_2^3$ instead of $m_2^2$ on the RHS.